# VSFM 2019 - Unable to read or write to NuGet.config

Tags: azure, nuget, devops, visual-studio-mac

After updating to the latest VSFM 2019 over the weekend I had suddenly started receiving fatal crashes while opening my mobile solution. This solution uses a private nuget package, and when and only when I have my credentials to this nuget source added via Preferences > Nuget > Sources do I get a fatal crash which I only have Stackshots for.

I do need this nuget source in my solution so i've tried re-adding it using a validated account which brings me to my roadblock.

When I add the source I seem to validate but i get the error *"Unable to read or write to /Users/$(whoami)/.config/Nuget/NuGet.config".*

[image]

The first major clue to this mystery is that the ONLY way I can authenticate is when I use the personal access token, indicated in step 6, as my password --> [Authenticate Access w/ PAT's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops)

Other things i've tried:

- Deleting nuget.config file
- Adding perms as below:

chown $(whoami) /Users/$(whoami)/.config/Nuget/NuGet.config

chown $(whoami) /Users/$(whoami)/.config/NuGet

- Manually adding read/write access to nuget.config
- re-install VSFM

I would like to add this Nuget source as an authenticated private Nuget source so that I can successfully build my solution.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated devs :)

Comment: This is a bug in NuGet 5.0 which affects the preview version Visual Studio for Mac 8.1. https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7948 The current workaround is to use an older Visual Studio for Mac version.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I left out an important clue. Apparently I was on the preview installation channel for VSFM . Switching back to stable channel/updating resolved my agony, Thanks.